# Sharding from application development point of view

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices, sharding

I read a lot regarding sharding, what i understand about this its a DB managment concept. When I come to know about application side, Lets take a example a spring boot microservice having huge table **orders** where it needs to be shard with a shard Key(K1) in table.

Let's say I decided to shard based on K1 fields using **range based  sharding** and will shard in multiple node of my MySQL DB.

Now I have the following question:

1. How this sharding is performed in existing data. Is it a background job?
2. What are the changes need to done in my existing application as currently its connecting to first Instance of MySQL db. while fetching data based on my shard key how can this application decided from which instance It need to request?

Comment: I think this question is way to broad and also somewhat subjective. For example if sharding of existing data should be a background job depends on your availability requirements. Doing it offline is certainly easier.

For a first overview, this article seems to reasonable: https://dzone.com/articles/challenges-of-sharding-mysql#:~:text=What%20Is%20Sharding%3F,separate%20set%20of%20data%20partitions.

Answer (score -1):

With Application Level Sharding you have a lot of options as you are the Application Developer/Architect who has the full control of it. There are a lot of options what you could do but for example here is one option or one Idea which could lead you in the right direction:

> How this sharding is performed in existing data. Is it a background
> job?

I guess by this you mean how do I separate or migrate the data from one Database to another database shard?

1. **Background job**. Yes having a background job is an option. With this background job you can move the data from one Db-shard to another Db-shard.
2. **Migration Script**. You can also write a migration script on your database level(SQL script) which will migrate all the data to other Db-shard.

**With both of these options you have to think about the fact if you system need to be running and operational all the time? Can you live with down-time?**

- If yes this can be more challenging. As while you are migrating you have to stay operational. Doing this in non-Business hours can help, doing it in chunks key by key and similar. Still this depends on your business.
- If no and you can have a down-time to do this then it will be much easier to separate the data to the appropriate Shards based on key. Here you do not have to consider a running system and some data mismatches in data. So if you can somehow can do it like this this would be much easier.

> What are the changes need to done in my existing application as
> currently its connecting to first Instance of MySQL db. while fetching
> data based on my shard key how can this application decided from which
> instance It need to request?

You have to provide that logic. Since it is on your application level you need to make that decision in code. In you DataAccess level code you need to know where to send your querys(or other sql statements): Service-Db-Shard1 or Service-Db-Shard2.
What you can do is for example in your Main Instance1 Db-Shard-1 you can have one table called Shards:

**shards Table**

| shard_key | database_instance |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | Service-Db-Shard1 |
| key2 | Service-Db-Shard2 |

**The shards table**

This table will contain the information where each shard data can be found. So the data which is sharded based on the key2 can be found in Service-Db-Shard2. Depending on your architecture you can put this table in one Main/Master(preferred option especially if you have some Read replicas to support downtime of Main instance) shard or in all shards(not preferred as it creates duplication). In addition you can cache this information in your micro-service Cache on startup and reuse its values from cache so you do not have to read this Table every time you need to execute an SQL statement on any other table.

**The good thing about this is** that you can control this and evolve this over time. For example in beginning when you do not have so much data separate/spread all your keys to 2 Instances(save money) and as the data grows you can increase the number of instances. Example:

**shards Table**

| shard_key | database_instance |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | Service-Db-Shard1 |
| key2 | Service-Db-Shard2 |
| key3 | Service-Db-Shard1 |
| key4 | Service-Db-Shard1 |
| key5 | Service-Db-Shard2 |

**Multiple shards in one instance**

Doing it like this gives you the option to have multiple shard keys data on the same instance to save money on to many resources. Keep in mind this does not work well with every key type. For example it could work quite well if you have a system which is a multi Customer/Tenant system and as your number of Tenants grows the data grows as well. Usually not all the Tenants have the same amount of data so having them in a dedicated Instance is not always the most efficient way to shard. This gives you this additional flexibility.

**Keep the shard key column in every table**

In addition you want to add to each of your tables the shard key column so that you can identify what needs to be moved where. Event when your data is distributed to multiple shard(instances) you still might want to keep this column for the fact that you might have multiple shard keys on the same instance and also having the option to migrate further(if needed).

**Before executing sql statements**

Before each sql statement against your DB you will need to get the Instance information from the "shards" Table and each sql statement to your "orders" Table or any other table which is sharded should contain the Sharding key in its filters.

**Data Access layer**

Consider DataAccess layer in your micro-service code, this is one good example why SOLID Principles and proper loose design of an DataAccess layer classes/modules and proper design can help you implement something like this easier. It is much easier to adjust a couple of classes to add additional step to find the Instance based on key and include the key in each query if your DataAccess layer code is done well.

**Conclusion**

This was just to give you an Idea how you could approach this. There are many ways how you can do this. It will heavily depend on your domain, your current service structure, your data, its Architecture, the way you have your Infrastructure setup and db deployments and migration strategy.